# Cannot access model from d3

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to link my model to a d3 visualization I have made. I would like this tooltip to automatically update with information from a database. I already have the database connected, and I can get the data to display in other parts of this document, but I cannot get the data to interact with d3.

Here is my code for the tooltip display:

```
div.html("Budget Amount: " + "<div id =" + d.deptno + "></div>")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
```

I have tried inserting my call to model (that works elsewhere in the document) within this snippet, so it looks like this:

```
div.html("Budget Amount: " + "<div id =" + d.deptno + ">{{model.budgets}}</div>")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
```

I had a feeling that maybe the d3 is loading after the Angular and JQuery, so this piece of code is not updated accordingly- I am not sure if that is the problem though!
Any tips that anyone could suggest to get this to work would be much appreciated.

Comment: `I had a feeling that maybe the d3 is loading after the Angular` - correct.  The d3 `.html` call has no concept of angular templates.  It's tough to answer your question further without more detail.  Is `model.bugets` available in your controller?  `div.html("Budget Amount: " + "<div id =" + d.deptno + ">"
 + model.budgets + "</div>")`

Comment: Yes! model.budgets is available in the controller. My code is here: https://github.com/MBTAnoldakowski/OrgChart-v2 if it is helpful! This part is in the public/visualization.html file, the controller is in budget.controller.client.js

Comment: I expected your `d3` code to be within the angular application.  Right now it seems you have it floating in `<script>` tags.  I would suggest you hit up some tutorials on more proper ways to mix angular and d3.